# In Rx.NET, how do I make a Subject to resemble TaskCompletionSource behavior?

Tags: c#, .net, system.reactive, reactivex, rx.net

In Rx.NET, how do I make a `Subject` to resemble `TaskCompletionSource.Task` behavior?

It needs to cache and reply the first event, even if completed. Neither `AsyncSubject` nor `ReplaySubject(bufferSize: 1)` would do that.

For example (let's call it `PromiseSubject`):

```cs
//var subj = new ReplaySubject<int>(bufferSize: 1);
var subj = new PromiseSubject<int>();

subj.Subscribe(i => Console.WriteLine(i));

subj.OnNext(1);
subj.OnNext(2);
subj.OnNext(3);
subj.OnCompleted();

subj.Subscribe(i => Console.WriteLine(i));

Console.ReadLine();
```

Expected output:

```
1
1
```

I can possibly cook it up using `TaskCompletionSource`, `TaskObservableExtensions.ToObservable` and a custom `SubjectBase`-derived subject implementation, but is there an elegant way of doing it using a composition of Rx operators?

**Updated**, my initial attempt via `TaskCompletionSource`:

```cs
public class PromiseSubject<T> : ISubject<T>
{
    private readonly TaskCompletionSource<(bool HasValue, T Value)> _tcs;
    private readonly IObservable<T> _observable;

    public PromiseSubject()
    {
        _tcs = new(TaskCreationOptions.RunContinuationsAsynchronously);
        _observable = _tcs.Task.ToObservable()
            .Where(r => r.HasValue).Select(r => r.Value!);
    }

    public void OnCompleted() =>
        _tcs.TrySetResult((false, default!));

    public void OnError(Exception error) =>
        _tcs.TrySetException(error);

    public void OnNext(T value) =>
        _tcs.TrySetResult((true, value));

    public IDisposable Subscribe(IObserver<T> observer) =>
        _observable.Subscribe(observer);
}
```

Comment: What is the desirable behavior in case an observer is subscribed after the `subj.OnNext(3);` and before the `subj.OnCompleted();`? Should it receive one or two `OnNext(1)` notifications?

Comment: @TheodorZoulias,  in this case the observer should receive one `OnNext` notification, immediately followed by `OnCompleted` notification. It's a one-off event cache.

Comment: @noseratio - Please note that once an subject is complete it cannot emit more values. That is the contract in Rx. Your sample code can never have the output you expect.

Comment: @Enigmativity, FWIW, `AsyncSubject` emits after (and only after) its completion, which I believe is its documented and desired behavior. It keeps emitting for new subscribers, too: https://dotnetfiddle.net/0SbFpM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a simplified version of Jeff Mercado's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72835741/11178549). I think that the desirable behavior can be achieved simply by completing a `ReplaySubject(bufferSize: 1)` after the first `OnNext`.

Actually an `AsyncSubject<T>`, as pointed out by @noseratio in [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72558093/in-rx-net-how-do-i-make-a-subject-to-resemble-taskcompletionsource-behavior#comment128650562_72836275), is even simpler, and also slightly more efficient because it stores its single value in a field instead of an array.

```
public class WriteOnceSubject<T> : ISubject<T>
{
    private readonly AsyncSubject<T> subject = new();

    public void OnNext(T value) { subject.OnNext(value); subject.OnCompleted(); }
    public void OnError(Exception error) => subject.OnError(error);
    public void OnCompleted() => subject.OnCompleted();

    public IDisposable Subscribe(IObserver<T> observer) => subject.Subscribe(observer);
}
```

So in this sequence of events:

```
writeOnceSubject.OnNext(1);
writeOnceSubject.OnNext(2);
writeOnceSubject.OnNext(3);
writeOnceSubject.OnCompleted();
writeOnceSubject.OnError(new Exception());
```

...all commands except the first will be no-ops. When the `writeOnceSubject` is subscribed later, it will emit the value `1` that is stored in its buffer, followed by an `OnCompleted` notification.

Comment: and I think it's safe to replace `ReplaySubject<T> subject = new(1)` with `AsyncSubject<T> subject = new()`, which has the "replay final item" behavior.

Comment: Hmm, funny, I initially used just a single replay subject as well and completed on the first `OnNext()` call when I initially looked at this, then decided it would be safer to have a separate subject. Thinking about it again, I guess it wasn't necessary after all.

Comment: On a side note, what do you folks think [about Subjects and the Rx contract](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72558093/in-rx-net-how-do-i-make-a-subject-to-resemble-taskcompletionsource-behavior#comment128663291_72558093)? Genuinely interested. Is it safe to say that only `IObservable` endpoint of a subject is bound by it?

Comment: @noseratio this question sounds a bit theoretical to me. You could consider opening a new question about it, although it might be closed as "opinion based". I think that the Rx in general tends to attract theoretical minds, who enjoy thinking about how things should be done in an ideal world. I consider myself to be more of a practical guy. If it works, it works. :-)

Comment: @TheodorZoulias, likewise! 

Answer (score 1):

What you describe sounds quite similar to the [`WriteOnceBlock<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.dataflow.writeonceblock-1) from the TPL Dataflow library. The dataflow blocks have a convenient extension method [`AsObservable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.dataflow.dataflowblock.asobservable), so based on this idea an implementation would look like this:

```
public class WriteOnceSubject<T> : ISubject<T>
{
    private readonly WriteOnceBlock<T> _block = new WriteOnceBlock<T>(x => x);

    public void OnCompleted() => _block.Complete();
    public void OnError(Exception error) => ((ISourceBlock<T>)_block).Fault(error);
    public void OnNext(T value) => _block.Post(value);

    public IDisposable Subscribe(IObserver<T> observer)
        => _block.AsObservable().Subscribe(observer);
}
```

Unfortunately this idea doesn't work. The subscribers of the `WriteOnceSubject<T>` are getting only an `OnCompleted()` notification. No `OnNext()` is emitted. I just posted a [bug report](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/70481) on GitHub about this issue.

---

**Update:** Here is [Microsoft's feedback](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/70481#issuecomment-1170538096) regarding the bug report, by Stephen Toub:

> `WriteOnceBlock` only ever has a single value, which is consumable any number of times, and as such the block completes as soon as it's been given a value. `AsObservable` checks whether a source has completed and takes that as an indication that no more data will be coming. So if you subscribe the observer prior to data being passed to the `WriteOnceBlock`, the `WriteOnceBlock` will dutifully propagate that data to linked targets prior to completing and the observer will receive it, but if the observer is subscribed after the `WriteOnceBlock` has completed, it'll assume no data is coming, and it'll itself signal completion.
>
> It's possible those checks could be removed from `AsObservable`, at some expense if the source has already completed, but at present `WriteOnceBlock` composability with `AsObservable` isn't perfect.

Comment: A great answer, tks! Though I'd like to avoid dependency on DataFlow if possible. I think a boundeded `Channel` could be used as a substation for `WriteOnceBlock`.

Comment: Meanwhile, I admit I specified a wrong output, sorry! There must be only two "1"s there, one for each subscriber (but that's what your version is supposed to be doing as well, IIRC).

Comment: So I've included a prototype using `TaskCompletionSource` in my question, which seems to be doing what I want.

Comment: @noseratio yep, your implementation is probably as good as it gets! The `Lazy<T>` might be redundant, but it shouldn't be harmful either.

Comment: Theodor, tks! I kinda hoped it can be composed with Rx operators but oh well...

Comment: Though I'd use a Lazy to reduce allocation for multiple subscribers. A very low-cost optimization, I think.

Comment: Another take, using `ReplaySubject and `Finally`: https://pastebin.com/raw/k8Dpcbna (not sure about all cases though, I like the TCS version more).

Comment: @noseratio I don't think that the `ReplaySubject<T>(1)` idea can work. If you push two messages before any observer has subscribed, most likely the second message will overwrite the first.

Comment: Yeah you're probably right. I also wary side effects in the pipleline, like `Do` or `Finally`.

Comment: @noseratio regarding the allocations associated with the `Lazy<T>`, check out [this](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Tr02LE) demo. Comment the `#define USING_LAZY` line at the top, to see whether the allocations are increased or reduced. :-)

Comment: A premature optimization strikes again!  Good spot, thanks for that (I've stolen it for my future self: https://gist.github.com/noseratio/8ec4801aed9a8592900ddd6f88f0dd4a :)

Answer (score 1):

You could write it in terms of two subjects, one replay subject to emit the value if set, and another to control initialization.

```
public class PromiseSubject<T> : ISubject<T>
{
    private readonly Subject<T> initialize = new();
    private readonly ReplaySubject<T> subject = new(1);
    public PromiseSubject() => initialize.Subscribe(subject);
    
    public void OnCompleted() => initialize.OnCompleted();
    public void OnError(Exception error) => initialize.OnError(error);
    public void OnNext(T value)
    {
        initialize.OnNext(value);
        initialize.OnCompleted();
    }

    public IDisposable Subscribe(IObserver<T> observer) => subject.Subscribe(observer);
}
```

Comment: Why not use a TCS as the base instead?

Comment: Well that's one implementation the OP explored already, but this can be implemented using RX constructs.

Comment: I meant wrapping a TCS instead of a Subject. That will definitely have the behavior of a TCS.

Comment: Tks! I've moved on with TCS (as in the q), but this is rather elegant. Probably could replace `ReplaySubject` of 1 item buffer with `AsyncSubject`?

Comment: @noseratio Oh yes, I believe that would work. I've never used that one but it sounds like it would do the job nicely.